# Azure reverse DNS Import

Tags: azure, dns

I was able to move my Forward Lookup zones to Azure DNS. I also need to move my reverse lookup Zone to Azure. Can I use the import CLI and import the zone `XX.XX.XX.in-addr.arpa`? When I try that, I get an error in the CLI, as follows:

> Cannot read Property 'push' of undefined

What is the best way for me to move the reverse DNS records up to Azure. Currently I have a lot of mail getting kicked back because reverse lookups from the far end are failing.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by a known bug in the Azure CLI for reverse-zone import.  It is fixed in the next CLI release, due mid-December.